# How to block VCL thread when running a shellexecute-like function

Tags: delphi

Apologies for improper terminology when referencing Delphi's VCL/main thread structure (if anyone has any resources to learn more about this I would appreciate it).

Basically, I have a VCL application where on a button click event, I want the user to be unable to interact with the initial VCL application that spawns the external exe.

I have a function called ExecuteExternalProcess that when passed the proper parameters, will not allow the next line(s) of code to execute until the external application has returned a value. This works well in other applications, but not so much when we are spawning the external exe from a VCL event.

Here is the Button Click Event that spawns the external process

```
procedure TMainForm.ButtonBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 error: Integer;
begin
 ExecuteExternalProcess('test.exe', '', '', True, false, false, error);
 showmessage('done');
end;
```

So this works, it doesn't display the 'done' message until the test.exe has finished executing. To reiterate, the issue is that while test.exe is running I can interact with the initial VCL application and do basically anything. I would like for the initial VCL application to stop completely and be inoperable until test.exe has finished executing.

Here is the code that spawns the exe if its any help(I am not the author I got it from here):

```
function ExecuteExternalProcess(const FileName, Params: string; Folder: string; WaitUntilTerminated, WaitUntilIdle, RunMinimized: boolean;
  var ErrorCode: integer): boolean;
var
  CmdLine: string;
  WorkingDirP: PChar;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Result := true;
  CmdLine := '"' + FileName + '" ' + Params;
  //if Folder = '' then Folder := ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(FileName));
  ZeroMemory(@StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo));
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  if RunMinimized then
    begin
      StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWMINIMIZED;
    end;
  if Folder <> '' then WorkingDirP := PChar(Folder)
  else WorkingDirP := nil;
  if not CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, false, 0, nil, WorkingDirP, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
    begin
      Result := false;
      ErrorCode := GetLastError;
      exit;
    end;
  with ProcessInfo do
    begin
      CloseHandle(hThread);
      if WaitUntilIdle then WaitForInputIdle(hProcess, INFINITE);
      if WaitUntilTerminated then
        repeat
          Application.ProcessMessages;
        until MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, hProcess, false, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1;
      CloseHandle(hProcess);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: If you want to block the VCL thread, stop calling `Application.ProcessMessages`. Why are you doing that? Of course, when you do that your UI will be ghosted, because it is blocked. And I doubt you want that. Perhaps a modal form would be best, and have the wait for the other process run out of a thread. However, your big problem is that you are using code you grabbed from the Internet without understanding it. It's unrealistic that you would do this and expect success. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: I don't think it's elitist to want to understand the code I use

Answer (score -1):

Why not just disable the tmainform.

Comment: Because I want to learn more about how the VCL/Main thread stuff works and that is just a hack.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really much of a hack. It's precisely how modal windows operate. If you do want to learn I suggest you start by trying to understand how your own code works. The code that you said you got from here but seem not to fully appreciate.